# Filtering JSON data and printing it

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I successfully [parse JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szv01.png) in my swift code but I want to print the ones that have a specific value. Right now in the code vc.packages prints all but I want to print only the ones who are:

- "typeCode" is FULL , "validTo" has a value, "stateCode" is valid

And how would I check that in my code and print it respectively?

```
func unzipPackage() {

    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoadingScreenController") as! LoadingScreenController

    let popup = STPopupController(rootViewController: vc)
    popup.style = .formSheet
    popup.hidesCloseButton = false
    popup.navigationBarHidden = true
    popup.backgroundView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
    popup.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    popup.present(in: self, completion: {

        DemosClient.sharedInstance.requestDataPackage()
            .then { response -> Void in

                vc.contentSizeInPopup = CGSize(width: 600, height: 800)
                vc.landscapeContentSizeInPopup = CGSize(width: 600, height: 800)


                vc.titles = (self.parseJSON(response: response))
                print(vc.titles)
                vc.packages = response["results"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []


                print(vc.packages)

            }
            .catch { error in

                print(error)
        }

        vc.loadData()
        vc.startTimer()


    })
```

Comment: "validTo" has a value ?

Comment: @NiravD as in it's not empty. For example in the JSON parse: validTo": <null> that has a null value, "validTo": 2017-05-11T07:57:07Z this one has a value.

Comment: You want array of contentUrl from this array of dictionary?

Comment: No no, figured it out. I just wanted to get the value of the contentUrl for another purpose which I figured. I had to do this: **let rowPackageUrl = (packages[indexPath.row]["contentUrl"] as! String)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can `filter` your `results` array and then assign result of `filter` to  `packages`.

```
let results = response["results"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []
vc.packages = results.filter {
    return ($0["typeCode"] as? String == "FULL") && 
           ($0["validTo"] != nil) && 
           ($0["stateCode"] as? String == "valid")
}
```

Comment: I tried it but I received an error with index being out of range on this line. cell.textLabel?.text = packages[indexPath.row]["name"] as! String
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = packages[indexPath.row]["releaseNotes"] as! String

Comment: @hamedabedini What do you mean by indexOutOfRange if you are working table or collection then make sure you are returning array count instead of some static value

Comment: I fixed that issue but when I run the code, it actually does not filter it.

Comment: I believe your code is right but I checked and thats not the issue. The above code is not working with me. I am not sure what could be the problem. It has errors. I tried @David answer below and it works for me just fine.

Comment: @hamedabedini If above answer is working and you are having issue with my one then there is only one issue with my solution, as of your Json having value INVALID for key stateCode I thought valid also in capital, try once changing valid in Lower case like in my latest edit so now no need to use for loop.

Comment: I understand and thank you for your input. However I did it with your solution but there is a flaw. It jumps the if condition. It does not go inside the if loop at all. It's never executed. I tried this: let results = response["results"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []
vc.packages = results.filter {
    return ($0["typeCode"] as? String == "FULL") }

Comment: If you could please tell me why is that happening, I would be delighted to go with your solution as in it's more efficient mate.

Comment: @hamedabedini Can you please tell me, what if condition you are talking about because there is no `if` in my solution. Also what do you mean by it It **jumps the if condition. It does not go inside the if loop at all.**?

Comment: Sorry about that  I didn't mean to say the if condition. **I mean it never goes inside: vc.packages = results.filter**

Comment: @hamedabedini it will sure goes just write code like i have done and put break point on return line it will execute every time, try once debugging like this

Comment: Got it to work. Updated the answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @hamedabedini Welcome mate :)

Comment: I have a question is related to the question: how can I get a JSON value for a key and save it to a variable. For example I want to get the value of key "contentUrl", how would I get the value for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the array of dictionaries and check the keys and their corresponding values. This piece of code should do the trick. I have not tested it, but is should work fine.

```
vc.packages = response["results"] as? [[String:Any]] ?? []

let filteredPackages = [[String:Any]]()
for package in vc.packages {
    guard let typeCode = package["typeCode"] as? String, typeCode == "FULL" else { continue }
    guard let stateCode = package["stateCode"] as? String, stateCode == "valid" else {continue}
    guard let validTo = package["validTo"] as? String, validTo != "" else {continue}
    filteredPackages.append(package)
}

print(filteredPackage)
```

Comment: Thank you Dávid, it worked and thanks for the learning curve.